# Ran as different User for Edgedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, runas

So I've been trying to get service account to run my code since my user has mfa auth, and this new service account is specifically created to overcome mfa for selenium purposes.

How I can use it via Edge is, right click and select Run as Diffrent user and login with the username/password from active directory of the company.

[image]

But I'm stucked for edgedriver. I tried a couple of trials with subprocesses with no success. from edgedriver.it's not a profile or user within my PC as well, and I tried to add the profile but it doesn't work as a profile somehow I need to start the browser itself as different user.

just to make it quick I'm coding in python first then I'll move it to C#. I'm language independent so any help would be appreciated.